# Taking screenshot of a specific window - C++ / Qt

Tags: c++, qt, screenshot

In Qt, how do I take a screenshot of a specific window (i.e. suppose I had Notepad up and I wanted to take a screenshot of the window titled "Untitled - Notepad")?
In their screenshot example code, they show how to take a screenshot of the entire desktop:

```
originalPixmap = QPixmap::grabWindow(QApplication::desktop()->winId());
```

How would I get the winId() for a specific window (assuming I knew the window's title) in Qt?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that's platform-specific. winIds are HWNDs on Windows, so you could call `FindWindow(NULL, "Untitled - Notepad")` in the example you gave.

Answer (score 2):

Look at QDesktopWidget class. It's inherited from QWidget so there is literally no problem of taking screenshot:

```
QPixmap pm(QDesktopWidget::screenGeometry().size());
QDesktopWidget::screen().render(&pm); // pm now contains screenshot
```

Comment: For version `4.8` I had to make little changes to your snippet. Mainly: create an object of type `QDesktopWidget` to call `screenGeometry()` and `screen()`, and change `screen().render()` to `screen()->render()`, as `screen()` returns a `QWidget*`.

Answer (score 1):

Also look at `WindowFromPoint` and `EnumChildWindows`. The latter could allow you to prompt the user to disambiguate if you had multiple windows with the same title.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Screenshot example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-desktop-screenshot-example.html)

In short:

```
QScreen *screen = QGuiApplication::primaryScreen();
if (screen)
    QPixmap originalPixmap = screen->grabWindow(0);
```

Comment: This answer is not about "Taking screenshot of a specific window". This is about taking screenshot of whole screen.

Answer (score -1):

Although this has already been answered, just for the sake of completeness, I'll add to Trevor Boyd Smith's post (see above) a code-snippet example:

```
void MainWindow::on_myButton_GUI_Screeshot_clicked()
{
    QPixmap qPixMap = QPixmap::grabWidget(this);  // *this* is window pointer, the snippet     is in the mainwindow.cpp file

    QImage qImage = qPixMap.toImage();

    cv::Mat GUI_SCREENSHOT = cv::Mat(         qImage.height(),
                                              qImage.width(), CV_8UC4,
                                      (uchar*)qImage.bits(),
                                              qImage.bytesPerLine()  );

    cv::imshow("GUI_SCREENSHOT",GUI_SCREENSHOT);
}
```